# How to draw text above the pie slice layers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation, cashapelayer

hello everyone I am new to Coregraphics and CoreAnimations. Can anyone suggest me where I did wrong to draw the text above the pie slice.

I have drawn the semicircle shape by using following code.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let selectedSliceIndex = 4;
    let sliceCount = 6;

    let slicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    let selectedSlicePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    slicePath.lineWidth = 1;
    slicePath.move(to: center)

    var angle: CGFloat = 0 - (CGFloat.pi / 2);
    let interval: CGFloat = (CGFloat.pi) / CGFloat(sliceCount)

    for i in 0 ... sliceCount {
        let x = center.x + (radius * cos(angle))
        let y = center.y + (radius * sin(angle))
        slicePath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: x, y: y))
        slicePath.move(to: center)

      //  button.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + raduis * sin(start + layoutDegree/(icons.count-1)*idx), self.center.y + raduis * cos(start + layoutDegree/(icons.count-1)*idx));

        // 1. create a gesture recognizer (tap gesture)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))

        // 2. add the gesture recognizer to a view
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


        let countLabel = UILabel()
        countLabel.text = "Rakesh"
        let size:CGFloat = 55.0
        countLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        countLabel.textAlignment = .center
        countLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        countLabel.frame = CGRect(x : 30 ,y : 0,width : 100, height :  40)

        countLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        countLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        countLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        countLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        countLabel.center = CGPoint.init(x: center.x + (radius * cos(angle + interval)) , y: center.y + (radius * sin(angle + interval)))

           // myLayer.frame = CGRect(x:center.x + (radius * cos(angle)), y: center.y + (radius * sin(angle)), width: 50, height: 40);

        self.addSubview(countLabel)
    //    countLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 60)


        if i == selectedSliceIndex {
            selectedSlicePath.move(to: center)
            selectedSlicePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: angle - interval, endAngle: angle, clockwise: true)
            selectedSlicePath.close()
        }
         angle -= interval;
    }

    // outer blue circle
    let semiCirclePath = UIBezierPath.init()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    semiCirclePath.close()
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()

    // lines
    UIColor.white.setStroke()
    slicePath.stroke()

    // selected slice
    UIColor(red: 67.0/255.0, green: 67.0/255.0, blue: 144.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
    selectedSlicePath.fill()
    UIColor.clear.setFill()

    // inner gray circle
    semiCirclePath.removeAllPoints()
    semiCirclePath.move(to: center)
    semiCirclePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 30, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat.pi / 2) , clockwise: true)
    UIColor(red: 67.0/255.0, green: 67.0/255.0, blue: 144.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
    semiCirclePath.fill()
 }.
```

the result should be

Actually I want to add text dynamically above the pie slice with the same angle slice has been portioned, but I am unable to achieve it. Please find the screenshot below:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You can use this library for reference : https://github.com/joshdhenry/SpinWheelControl

Comment: @ Jayesh Thanki  took its reference its working now .